# How to manipulate tables in Excel using Python

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have the following load profile in Excel as .xlsx:
[Load Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jolqp.png)

In column A, date and time stamps are entered in the format DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm. This is a user-defined format. Without this formatting, the table would look like this:
[Load Profile Without Custom Formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6usi.png)

I want to make two changes to this table and save the modified table to a new Excel file.

**The first change:**
The following date and time stamp is to be searched for in column A "01.01.2021 02:00". When the criterion has been found, the four rows below it for column A and B are to be deleted completely. In Excel, rows 12, 13 and 14 would be selected and deleted completely. Below the result before and after:
[Before Edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19hKs.png)
[After Edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Em76x.png)

Note that after deleting the rows, there are no empty rows between the search criterion and the subsequent stamps.

**The second change:**
The following date and time stamp should be searched for in column A: "01.01.2021 03:45". When the criterion has been found, these steps should be completed:

1. Two lines above the search criterion, the entire lines (i.e. from 16 up to the search criterion in line 18) are to be copied. This means a total of 3 lines, including the line where the search criterion is.
2. Three new lines are to be inserted below the search criterion and the values from the first step are to be inserted in these new lines.

[Before Edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwfMR.png)
[After Edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Pjjy.png)

This is currently my approach, but I do not know how to implement what I described above:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Path to Excel File
excel_data = 'a.xlsx'

# Read the Excel file and select the worksheet
df = pd.read_excel(excel_data, sheet_name='Sheet1', engine='openpyxl', header=None)

# Rename the columns
df.columns = ['DateTime', 'Power']

# Extract the data from line 3
df = df.iloc[2:]

# Save the data in a new DataFrame
date_time = df['DateTime']
power = df['Power']

# Create a new DataFrame with the data
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime': date_time, 'Power': power})

# Save the DataFrame in a new Excel file
new_excel_file = 'a_edit.xlsx'
new_df.to_excel(new_excel_file, index=False, engine='openpyxl')

print(f'The date has been successfully saved to {new_excel_file}.')

# Search Criterion
search = 44283.0729166667

# Search for the search criterion in both data frames
line_date_time = new_df.index[new_df['DateTime'] == search].tolist()
line_power = new_df.index[new_df['Power'] == search].tolist()
```